# Visual Studio 'Data UI Cutomization'

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

In 'Data Source' window from where I can drag and drop data sources to a form, I can set the field to different control 'Textbox', 'Label', etc. But I used to be able to set them to some third party component (in this case Telerik's components). Just now I started to work on my project again, and these third party components do not appear there anymore.

I click on the choice list, customize ... I get the window 'Options' width 'Data UI customization' selected, there I used to be able to select Telerik's control, but again they don't appear there anymore.

How could I customize this ?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar back in December... apparently with some windows updated / service patches, it corrupted something.  I couldn't even pick a UI control of my OWN.  I even tried by creating a BRAND NEW project, created a single class and it would not appear in the toolbox to be put into a form anywhere.

By doing some digging, I came across a blog (don't remember where), but it directed me to do the following.  Get to your Visual Studio Command Prompt.  There should be one in your Startbar menus specifically under your Visual Studio icon group.

Once at the command prompt, do

```
DEVENV /setup
```

This apparently does some fresh "cleanup" settings and fixed whatever was stopping the classes from being displayed.  As soon as I did, and re-started VS, the class libraries appears and able to be put into forms no problem.

Comment: It says "The operation could not be completed"

Comment: @user1103990, that may be true, but did it reset SOME of the flags that ultimately allow the use of class controls again?  Again, since my instance was in December, I don't remember if I had the same response.  You may need to run it as admin though.